# Processing of multiple request(s) of jsp in webserver

Tags: jsp, servlets

How does process of jsp happens when there about more than one request is coming to the server? whether it creates individual objects for all the requests or creates an object and process the every request as thread?

if anyone explains with image/diagram then it will be helpful for everyone.

Thanks for explaining the concept in advance.

Comment: Please try to do some research on your questions before you ask them yourself.  The first result when I googled "how jsp works" led me to this page - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_architecture.htm.  Which provides almost the same exact answer as Yagnesh did below with many other chapters detailing how the jsp model works in detail.

Answer (score 1):

JSP page Or Request to JSP processed in the following way :

1. The user requests the JSP page through a URL ending with a `.jsp` file
   name.
2. Upon noting the .jsp file name extension in the URL, the
   `Servlet Container` of the Web server invokes the JSP container.
3. The JSP container locates the JSP page and **translates it to servlet class if this is the first time it         has been requested.** Translation includes producing servlet code in a .java file and then   compiling the .java file to produce a servlet .class file.
4. Translating a JSP page into a servlet automatically incorporates standard servlet programming overhead into the generated servlet code, such as implementing the javax.servlet.jsp.HttpJspPage interface and generating code for its service method.
5. The JSP container triggers instantiation and execution of the page implementation class.

Than rest is working same as Servlet. The servlet (JSP page instance) will then process the HTTP request, generate an HTTP response, and pass the response back to the client.
Servlet Containers usually manages concurrent requests by creating a new Java thread for each request.

All the above mentioned steps can be shown below in the following diagram:
[image: JSP process step]

I hope this will help you to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: lolz at not accepting his answer or upvoting it but commenting on how it helped solve your problem.  Please be courteous of other users and look up how stack overflow is meant to be used, you should be clicking the checkmark next to his answer to indicate it helped you solve your problem.