# where does the scriptlet & html code stored in j2ee

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

i could not find answer of this question anywhere. i only know what & why we use scriplet. `but where does scrip-let stored` exactly ? ( asked by my interviewer)

my answer was: its just a tag, defined in jre(j2ee), where we can write our java code in jsp page. So do really scrip-let code stored anywhere?

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<%
    // This is a scriptlet.  Notice that the "date"
    // variable we declare here is available in the
    // embedded expression later on.
    System.out.println( "Evaluating date now" );
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSP file is converted into JAVA file. Which is work as same servlet.
This conversion take place when you request that JSP first time and is it in your tomcat server.
Java file which is created based on the JSP has method `_jspInit()`,`_jspDestroy()` and [_jspService()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/HttpJspPage.html) as same as any servlet.

Your scriptlet part are goes into `_jspService()` method with all other java and html part which is written in using `out.write()` function.

And it will store at location :

```
{TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR}/work/Catalina/{CONTEXT_NAME}/{WEBCONTENT_DIR}/org/apache/jsp/{PATH_TO_JSP_PAGE}
```

You can find one `.java` file and one `.class` file inside that folder for each JSP page.

For details on [How JSP work see this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909302/processing-of-multiple-requests-of-jsp-in-webserver/24911515#24911515)